# ontology- Storing Java Date in XMLSchema#dateTime

Tags: java, xml, ontology

I created a File System ontology in protege. I have set range of file created date as dateTime, as depicted in below code.

```
<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/administrator/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-5#created">
  <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime"/>
  <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/administrator/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-5#File"/>
  <rdfs:comment>Time when the file was last accessed.</rdfs:comment>
  <rdfs:label>fileLastAccessed</rdfs:label>
```

in date create property I am storing java date `Date date = new Date();` (after casting to String)

it store correctly as:

```
<File rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/administrator/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-5#8117c6b9-3db8-4ab9-8de4-ba67f52ac615">
<created>Wed Apr 16 14:37:30 PKT 2014</created>
<hasPath>/Documents/Untitled Document 5</hasPath>
```

My question is that: is it safe / correct way to store java Date in `XMLSchema#dateTime` ?

Am I doing it correctly or wrongly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't a correctly formatted value for XML Schema dateTime.  Instead it should be in the following format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
```

You could leverage a `SimpleDateFormat` to control the `String` representation or use `XMLGregorianCalendar` instead of `Date`.

Comment: Instead, can I use `yyyy-MM-dd'at'HH:mm:ss` ? because I need time in 24hrs format instead of am-pm

Comment: @user363565 - Yes, actually that is what you need to use.  I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: once if I save it in xml after converting in `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` format. Would it be possible to store it again in java date object. Because, later I would need it  for Date comparisons in java.

Comment: @user363565 - Yes you can convert it back using `SimpleDateFormat` or `XMLGregorianCalendar` as well.